# Two particle state for $T = 0$

Tags: nuclear-physics, isospin-symmetry

A state of T=1 could be imagined as two protons or two neutrons or else half the time first particle proton second a neutron and other half time vice-versa but how would one imagine a T=0 state? Just as S is the total spin quantum number of particles with spin s1 and s2 where S=s1 + s2 (vector ally added) in the same way T is the total isospin quantum number obtained by adding the isospins of individual particles.

Comment: What is $T$ here?

Comment: Have edited in view of above comments. T is the total isospin quantum number.

Comment: Could you explain your question? I don't know what all those half the time other half the time means.

Comment: A sum of two different quantum states with equal weights would if measured a million times result in  half of measurements would give one state the other half another. can say it this way.

Comment: Is the question still actual? I dont understand too much the question - $T=0$ means - first of all - you have $N=Z$ in your system. You also dont measure particles - like sometimes $proton$ and sometimes $neutron$. It is always a pair with clearly defined projection $T_z$. So - one more try? I know the isospin is really a strange concept.

Comment: Quite right you do not measure particles but I have a drawn an analogy to the singlet spin state.

Comment: In this analogy - it is better not to speak about *free particles* (they couple with momentum L), and rather $p$ and $n$ in s-state in the nucleus.  To not mix with $L$. Then you have exactly mirror situation isospin x spin. Well - the most difficult thing is to formulate the question...

Answer (score 1):

As the question remains some time without an answer, I suggest this:

The total isospin $T$ of two particles - in analogy with the spin - comes out from a summation of its components. Those components are $proton$ and $neutron$, having $T=1/2$ with oposite projections $T_z=1/2$ and $T_z=-1/2$.

In $pp$ or $nn$ system, the situation is clear, the total $T_z=\pm1$, the total isospin must be $T\ge1$.

In $pn$ system, the total projection $T_z=0$, so, following the rules $T\ge0$.

It is possible to find both variants,

- the ground state of the $deuteron$ has $T=0$,
- the first excited (virtual) deuteron  state has $T=1$.

There is no principal difference between the two variants for $deuteron$, but the $T=0$ is a little bit more bound ( just 2.2 MeV of 2 x 935 MeV total mass). Why? - this is due to the tensor character of the nuclear forces. Aligned spins of $p-n$ system have stronger interaction, but it looks we are in a circle now.